# Time Decay Formula for Conversion Attribution

Tags: consumerweb

### Question:

What is the Time Decay formula that web analytics packages use to distribute credit across the multiple sessions associated with a user before a conversion?

### Context:

All web analytics packages like Google Analytics rely on the concept of:

1. **USERS** *visitors, ie unique cookied browsers.* Users have many...
2. **SESSIONS** *visits, ie sets of pageviews within close time proximity.*
3. **CONVERSIONS**  *a success event such as a sign-up which can occur during a session.*

These analytics packages allow you to distribute the credit of a single conversion across all the preceding sessions because each played a part in leading the user to conversion. One such model is Time Decay, which gives a diminishing share of credit to sessions further from the conversion.

Time Decay Visual: (1st session) ▁ ▂ ▃  ▅ ▆ (conversion)

[more info on attribution models](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1662518?hl=en).

### Sample Data:

I am assuming the data required would be:

- `n` - the total number of sessions a user has before a conversion
- `t` - the total duration of time from the user's first session to conversion
- `tbc` - the individual time before conversion for each session

So for three different sample users, data may look like this:

`UserID  n   t   Session#    Timestamp   TBC Conversion in session?
User1   4   12  1           2015-10-01  12  No
User1   4   12  2           2015-10-06  7   No
User1   4   12  3           2015-10-11  2   No
User1   4   12  4           2015-10-13  0   YES
User2   3   4   1           2015-10-09  4   No
User2   3   4   2           2015-10-09  4   No
User2   3   4   3           2015-10-13  0   YES
User3   1   0   1           2015-10-14  0   YES`

Comment: Welcome to the site, @Andy H.! Can you provide a little more information on your question and the format of your data here? I'm not sure your question is yet understandable to someone who hasn't already been thinking about it :)

Comment: Thanks, @Andy H.! That's much clearer. I don't think I have the expertise to answer this, but this should help you get the help you need!

Comment: Thanks for sharing this post. I am using your model for the time-decay attribution modeling. Can you please tell me what is the unit for 't' and 'tbc' since both are time and the values in the data are integers. I appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

### Here's one solution:

*using the following data:*

**USER-LEVEL:**

- `fss` *first session start (timestamp) - time of first pageview of
  first session for that user*
- `css` *converting session start (timestamp) - time of the first pageview of session where user converted*
- `ns` *number of sessions (int) - total # of sessions
  before conversion for user*

**SESSION-LEVEL:**

- `ss` *session start (timestamp) - timestamp of first pageview in session*

**FORMULA:** *calculated for each session*

1. FOR FIRST SESSION: Attribution Credit is just linear: *(or really whatever you want to make it)*
    [image: linear credit]
2. ALL OTHER SESSIONS:

   - First calculate the SUM of all session's "time before conversion":
     [image: sum(tbc)]
   - Then Calculate the credit for each session:
     [image: sc formula]

it isn't perfect because it distributes credit based on the relative position of a session in the User's lifetime.  Ideally you have a preset halflife (like 7 days) so that comparison is more consistent.